# Comment textarea disappears after changing screen orientation on SE Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

I discovered that today in version 1.0.71, it happens on both smartphone and tablet. The content isn't lost, if you tap on **Add comment** again, it reappears, only the cursor has moved to the beginning. When adding an answer, everything is ok.

One other thing on the smartphone, when you change orientation to landscape, the keyboard disappears too.

The tablet is a Nexus 10 with 5.1.1, the smartphone is a BQ Aquaris E6 with 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v1.0.83<sup>or somewhere before that</sup>, it has been fixed: the comment textarea won't disappear, and the cursor position is retained.

[image: comment portrait] [image: comment landscape]

---

Side note: when changing the orientation to landscape, a keyboard will disappear if it's set to *fullscreen mode*. Some keyboards have this setting (e.g. Google Japanese Input [both portrait & landscape], Hacker's Keyboard [only landscape]), others don't have (e.g. Google Keyboard with landscape fullscreen mode). Whether it's a bug of the app or not, I don't know.

[image: comment portrait - Japanese IME] [image: comment landscape - Japanese IME]

Comment: I just checked with both tablet and smartphone, it looks ok now.