# Issues with android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app

Here are some issues I recently experienced with the android Stack Exchange app:

- It is insensitive to my pressing the soft keys on the sides of the home button (only sometimes);
- Sometimes tag lookup won't work;
- As I type, no related questions are suggested, so I can't check if there is a duplicate before asking.

So are those three buggy behaviors only taking place on my phone? Is there any reason for any of them?

Comment: Way too many questions. Second one already reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263919/textarea-disappears-when-adding-a-comment-and-then-change-orientation). Third question reported [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238268/cannot-find-some-answers-in-mobile-app/). As for the rest of your app questions, all probably related to very slow connection. Not saying you should not report, but most chances they'll be declined or tagged as status-norepro.

Comment: @ShadowWizard If it were slow connection it should appear after some time, which it doesn't. Thx for the links, looking at them in a sec.

Comment: Maybe the timeout in those cases is silently ignored, unlike timeout on other places like loading questions. Not 100% sure, but that's my guess. Like I said, you can edit this question and leave only those three, which might be all related, and also take out the paragraph about mobile site. (You can post that as new question :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard singled out the three questions, leaving the others for the record with links.

Comment: No, pointless to repeat something that is already reported and more critical, as it stands this is too broad as it spans several issues. (not my downvote, but I did vote to close, and can retract if this will be edited properly)

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it fine now? And if you voted to close, why do I see no notice of it under the question? I remember seeing the number of close votes on a TeX question…

Comment: You don't have sufficient rep here. You need 250 in order to see them.

Comment: I see @PatrickHofman.

Comment: Cheers, OK now. :)